# Nvidia driver on Debian 11 Rock4C+

Tags: nvidia

I'm encountering a problem while attempting to install the Nvidia driver on my Debian system. I'm using Debian 11 "Bullseye" on a Radxa Rock4 computer. My efforts to install the Nvidia driver have hit a roadblock due to issues related to dependencies and configuration. My Rock4C+ is new but other stuff works fine like Gimp.

Upon executing sudo apt install nvidia-driver, I'm presented with the following error message (the end of it):

```
Removing old nvidia-current-470.182.03 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 470.182.03
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new nvidia-current-470.182.03 DKMS files...
Building for 5.10.110-11-rockchip
Building initial module for 5.10.110-11-rockchip
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.10.110-11-rockchip (aarch64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/470.182.03/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-kernel-dkms (--configure):
 installed nvidia-kernel-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up libglew2.1:arm64 (2.1.0-4+b1) ...
Setting up blender-data (2.83.5+dfsg-5+deb11u1) ...
Setting up libopencv-videoio4.5:arm64 (4.5.1+dfsg-5) ...
Setting up libblosc1 (1.20.1+ds1-2) ...
Setting up libboost-locale1.74.0:arm64 (1.74.0-9) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver:
 nvidia-driver depends on nvidia-kernel-dkms (= 470.182.03-1) | nvidia-kernel-470.182.03; however:
  Package nvidia-kernel-dkms is not configured yet.
  Package nvidia-kernel-470.182.03 is not installed.
  Package nvidia-kernel-dkms which provides nvidia-kernel-470.182.03 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libspnav0 (0.2.3-1+b2) ...
Setting up libopencolorio1v5 (1.1.1~dfsg0-7) ...
Setting up libopenvdb7.1 (7.1.0-2+b3) ...
Setting up libopenimageio2.2:arm64 (2.2.10.1+dfsg-1+deb11u1) ...
Setting up blender (2.83.5+dfsg-5+deb11u1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-kernel-dkms
 nvidia-driver
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've taken several steps to address this issue, including refreshing the package list, running `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, and even attempting to install an older version of the Nvidia driver using `sudo apt install nvidia-driver=470.103.01-1~bpo11+1`. However, the problem persists.

Here are some of the Nvidia-related packages that are currently installed on my system:

```
nvidia-driver nvidia-driver-libs nvidia-driver-bin nvidia-kernel-dkms
```

I've also reviewed the log file for the nvidia-kernel-dkms installation (`/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/470.182.03/build/make.log`), although I'm unsure how to accurately interpret the information contained therein.

My Kernel as below:

```
radxa@rock-4c-plus:~$ uname -r
5.10.110-11-rockchip
```

I would greatly appreciate assistance in diagnosing and resolving this issue. If anyone has encountered similar problems or can offer guidance on potential next steps, I would be immensely grateful for your support.

Comment: I suspect the important information is indeed in `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/470.182.03/build/make.log`.  Usually start by looking for the word "error" preferably near the end of the file, but make can do things in a funny order so don't be surprised if the error isn't at the end.